# Websocket not receiving messages from Django Channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I'm currently working on a project using Django Channels for WebSocket communication. However, I'm facing an issue where the WebSocket connection is established successfully, but messages are not being received on the client side.

WebSocket connection is established without errors.

I've verified that the Django Channels server is sending messages.

However, the client-side WebSocket does not seem to receive any messages
my asgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
import transposys_main.routing
import django
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'transposys_main.settings')
django.setup()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": get_asgi_application(),
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        URLRouter(
            transposys_main.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

`consumer.py`

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class DepartmentCreatedConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket connected: {self.channel_name}")
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket disconnected: {self.channel_name}")

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        logger.info(f"WebSocket message received: {text_data}")

        try:
            text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
            message_type = text_data_json.get('type')
            message = text_data_json.get('message')

            if message_type == 'department.created':
                logger.info(f"New Department: {message}")

        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            logger.error(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")

    async def department_created(self, event):
        try:
            logger.info(f"Department created event received: {event['message']}")
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'type': 'department.created',
                'message': event['message'],
            }))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error sending WebSocket message: {e}")
```

routing.py:
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumers import DepartmentCreatedConsumer

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/department_creation/$', DepartmentCreatedConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

this is fn in post view

```
try:
                    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
                    message = {
                        'type': 'designation.created',
                        'message': f"New designation created: {designation_name}"
                        # Add more data if needed
                    }
                    # Add async_to_sync wrapper
                    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)('notifications', message)
                except:
                    return Response({'error': 'Something went wrong'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Server Configuration:
WSGI: waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 transposys_main.wsgi:application
ASGI: daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 transposys_main.asgi:application

Despite successful connection, no messages are received in the HTML page or console.